# Ionic 1.x + Firebase: add several objects to DB using a loop?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add to my `ionic 1.x` app offline capabilities by storing some data to `localStorage` while offline, and then once online again (networking issues for example) sync the data to the cloud. I came up with this service, however I dont know if this is the correct way to go. Is there a more correct way of pushing several objects to `firebase` at once\one after another?

```
.service("syncOFFLINE_Service", function (fireBaseService) {
  var dataArray= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("offline_data"));

  this.syncExpenses = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
      fireBaseService.addDataToDB(dataArray[i],firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
    }

    localStorage.removeItem('offline_expenses');//clear offline data once the loop is over
  }

})
```

And this is the service that adds data (one object at a time) to `firebase`:

```
this.addDataToDB = function (expense, uid) {
  var newExpenseKey = firebase.database().ref().child('expenses').push().key;
  var updates = {};

  var keyByDate = "somekey";

  updates['/user-expenses/' + uid + '/' + keyByDate + '/'+ newExpenseKey] = expense;

  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
};
```